# Making a loop and storing the results in a matrix

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R which consists of intensity values (odd-numbered columns) and numbers of pixels for each bin (even-numbered columns). I want to sum the values in column 2 for values of column 1 within some range (binning). 
The odd-numbered columns have values 0-5000, I want to divide them in bins of 200.

For this, I thought of checking the column 1 if it is within my desired range, convert the true/false results to numeric, multiply with column 2 and sum the result; it gives me the desired number. The code is as follows:

```
bin_height = as.numeric(g11_6[,1] >= 200 & g11_6[,1] < 400)*g11_6[,2]
sum(bin_height)
```

Now I wanted to make a loop so that R calculates the results for each bin (400-600, 600-800...)
How can I write a loop for this?

I tried:

```
for (k in 1:25){
bin_height = as.numeric(g11_6[,1] >= 200*(k-1) & g11_6[,1] < 200*k)*g11_6[,2]
sum(bin_height
}
```

but it does not do anything (doesn't give error, either)... How can I get the result for each bin?

Comment: Please consider wrapping your code into highlighted code blocks for the others to read with ease.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting and the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need somewhere to store the results.

```
results <- numeric(25)
for (k in 1:25){
bin_height <- as.numeric(g11_6[,1] >= 200*(k-1) & g11_6[,1] < 200*k)*g11_6[,2]
results[k] <- sum(bin_height)
}
```

Then you should have all the information you want in the `results` vector.